# ios growth animation CGAffineTransformMakeScale moves around

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation

I am animating a tree that grows. Like a Tree, I want my UIImage to stay in the same place, so that when I scale it up it appears to grow.

Right now its jumping around, i.e. its growing from the centre - I need it to grow from the bottom.

Is there a way to set the origin/base of the animation. So the scale animation works from the bottom.

Hope that makes sense. here is my code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
tree.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.25f);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wish to look at the **CALayer** class for this and set the anchorPoint to the centerbottom

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    self.outletTestView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
    self.outletTestView.layer.position = CGPointMake(100, 300);
}
```

Don't forget to include:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

And use for the scaling:

```
CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformScale ( CGAffineTransform t, CGFloat sx, CGFloat sy );
```

Like so:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
tree.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(tree.transform, 1.0f, 1.25f);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: unfortunately it still jumps to the right. I am setting it once in the  viewDidLoad function. Do I have to set it before the transform?

Comment: if I didn't have QuartzCore then there would be no animation. It translates to the right when I animate.

Comment: Yep that worked. It was the viewDidLayoutSubviews that did the trick